# Entering Time data in excel in h:mm:ss format (adding a leading 0: for the hours)

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I copy the information from the system I use it gives me the times as :23:12 and I have to add a leading zero for all of the fields I copy (about 800), I think there should be a way for this zero to be added automatically but I can't find a way, red arrow is after I modified manually adding the zero, below is how I get it from the system I use.
Red is after I modified manually adding the zero, below is how I get it from the system I use

[image]

Comment: What is your time format in *Control Panel > Region*? A screenshot will help the most.

Comment: when they come in `:23:12` it is a text string and not a true time  you will need to do something like: `=IF(left(a1,1)=":",--("00"&a1),a1)`  Then format it `hh:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, while you do need a formula to do this as the mechanism that would help the pasting won't do here because you have two `:`'s, not just the leading one, you don't actually need the `IF` test. (And that mechanism might have been separated from affecting pasting anyway in recent Excel versions. Either way, it's no help.)

Just:

```
=--("00"&A1)
```

as `Scott Craner`'s comment includes in the `IF` test is sufficient.

That is because the "00" you prepend to the string does not affect the value for a pasted datum that has an hour value already. "001:23:45" is the same as "1:23:45" for this work.

Or, if your spreadsheets are subject to review, or you plan to pass their work on to someone someday after you are promoted, don't `coerce` the text result of `"00"&A1` into a numerical value but rather just use a direct function such as:

```
=VALUE("00"&A1)
```

which will make the intended action clear to a reviewer/approver or your after-promotion replacement.

As far as the formula goes, you can create a whole "helper" sheet to put the formula into and paste there, then copy/paste the formula output to the normal place for the data. That way it does not affect the layout of your working sheets. But unless you automate that with a macro and a button to launch it, it would really only be good for you as a user because many not-you users would mess that up all the time.

Other solutions, probably less satisfactory, would include pasting into a different program, Word, or NotePad++ perhaps. They should let you do `RegEx` search and replace to remove a leading character, and specifically only that `:` which could be replaced with `00:` at the same time, or just one to prepend the 00's if the leading character is the `:`. Again though, not good for not-you users so...

Power Query would do it in a trice as well. If you have a "blank canvas" you paste into, PQ could output its results onto that space. If you perhaps add the new data to the end of things, it can output to its own table and you can copy/paste the output from there to your canvas. (Somehow no one would call that a "helper" anything while sneering at the above suggestion about a helper sheet...)

VBA can, of course, do it in a trice as well and fit precisely your canvas. But I have no great skills with VBA, bringing it up mostly for completeness, so shall not offer much past mentioning it's doable for someone with some knowledge and would not be much, or hard.

Answer (score 0):

Add a secondary column with 0, enter the formula:

```
=TEXT((C1&A1),"h:mm:ss")
```

[image]